# SwiftUI: TabBar inside of a split NavigationView?

Tags: swiftui, ipad, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview, ipados

I have an iPad app I am writing with SwiftUI.  I would like to have a split NavigationView with the left-hand (navigation) side displaying a TabView and the right-hand (content) side displaying other various views.  I am seeing some strange behavior, however.  If I have, say, 4 tabs I only see tabs 2-4 displayed.  Tab 1 does not appear.  If I only have 2 tabs, though, I see that Tab 1 is displayed FAR to the left to the point it is partially cut off.

I setup my NavigationView like this:

```
struct SidebarContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabbedNavigationView()
            Text("DETAIL")
        }
    }
}
```

My TabView is then setup like this:

```
struct TabbedNavigationView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            EmptyView()
            
            Text("TAB 1")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Tab 1")
                }
            
            Text("TAB 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Tab 2")
                }
            
            Text("TAB 3")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Tab 3")
                }

            Text("TAB 4")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Tab 4")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect all tabs to be visible on the left.  Instead, when the view renders it looks like this.

[image]

You see that "Tab 1" isn't displayed at all, even though it's obvious that "Tab 1" is the default selected tab (as evidenced by "TAB 1" being displayed on the navigation side).  Any idea why I can't get the TabBar inside my NavigationView to play nicely?  Is there something more I need to do here?

Comment: What happens if you replace `NavigationView` by `NavigationStack` and remove `EmptyView`?

Comment: Also, this is the first time I see a `TabView` in the left panel of an iPad and so I'm really curious how users could handle it. Why not using a "Segmented Controls"?

Comment: TabView should always be at the top per HIG

Comment: Yes, each tab should have its own NavigationStack.